# Camera's pts and dts jumps issue

Tags: video, camera, ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg library in my code for capturing rtsp streams from cameras and writing in flv. If I capture streams from only one camera and camera has only video stream then there's no any errors, I got first packet with pts and dts 1698557894 and other packets' pts and dts slowly increases. But if camera has video and audio streams, then strange things occur. For example, video packets pts and dts begin with 1698557894 and slowly increase, and audio starts with 0 then slowly increases and after ~50 packets jumps to value 151004317 and slowly increase. Another situation, when audio begins with 0 and slowly increases, and video begins from 1785662594 and after ~70 packets jumps to 234722 and slowly increase. Such behaviour do not allow flv segment muxer to write files, it just returns some EINVAL value.

Also if I try to capture streams from two cameras, first camera has only video and another has video and audio, then first camera packets' pts and dts are ok. But another camera has video and audio pts/dts values which are very different. av_read_frame returns video packet with pts/dts value 1811924055, which rescales to 557003451 in flv muxer and audio 4456027604, which rescales to 557003451, but these values must be almost equal!

So, the questions are:
0) why do these jumps occur in the beginning of capturing? is it a problem with camera or it is just some ffmpeg issue?
1) can such jump occur after some long period? how I should handle it?
2) why camera's video and audio have so different pts/dts values?

Answer (score 2):

There are a  lot of things going on there. Frankly, I would write it off as an incorrectly implemented RTMP stream. But there are some points I can make that could help you move forward. First RTMP always uses 1kHz clock and can use a 24 or 32 bit timestamp. So timestamp overflows are common at are 4.6 hours and 49.7 days. Next RTMP can specify time deltas, so its possible to over flow 24 bit and have the next couple frames go over 16777215 before it wraps back to 0 (or really, 0 + delta). And finally 4456027604 is more than 32 bits. So ffmpeg is doing something to the timestamps before you get them, or you have a bug in your code. Good Luck!